# What is the proper way of managing ROS packages during deployment?

Tags: ros

I have a robot with all the necessary source files in a ROS workspace. I was told that for security purpose, the robot should only contain the built binaries instead of the source files. How do I make such deployment process simpler once I have more robots?

For example, I made a github repository for storing the source files of my workspace. How can I utilize the github actions to build the source files and pull only the binaries into other robot's PC? What is the proper way of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is *the* proper way of doing this. Some people create debian packages with the compiled ROS packages, and distribute those (either directly or by running their own apt repo). But more common by now, I think, is to build and push docker images.